# Style in text view doesn't work

Tags: android

I have style for textview:

```
<style name="MoreSettingsItem">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/drivelog_7BU</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/textview_white_selector</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">@dimen/drivelog_2BU</item>
    <item name="android:drawableRight">@drawable/arrow_right</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily" tools:ignore="NewApi">sans-serif</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/drivelog_BU</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/drivelog_2BU</item>
</style>
```

I want to add border so I add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/textview_white_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/textview_bottom_line"/>
</selector>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/background_color"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/selector_color"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/textview_bottom_line"/>
</transition>
```

but this solution doesnt work. Any idea why?

Comment: So what do you want to do exactly here, you wanna have have so transition when the textView is clicked or what ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to differentiate each item tag with different state. because if you are not mentioned any state to the item tag it will take that item as default item. but in your selector you have two different items with only drawable then it wont work remove one item tag in selector then it will work. modify like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/textview_white_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>
</selector>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/textview_bottom_line"/>
</transition>
```

if you want to add any border.or any other modifications then create custom shape and assign that to the drawable it will work. i hope.